# TypeError ( 'str' object is not callable )

Tags: python, sikuli

I know these questions have been asked before, but I still don't understand. :-( 
Example code:

```
nCount = 1
class Vrijdag():
    def __init__(self):
        self.day5('Dummy', nCount)
    def day5(self, value1, value2):
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2
        value2B = str(value2)
        print(value1)
        print(value2B)
Vrijdag()
```

This line: `value2B = str(value2)`
Returns me this error: `[error] TypeError ( 'str' object is not callable )`

And I don't get why. 
I used it before, and then it was working fine. 
It is not that I am changing `value2` 
Can anyone explain this to me?

Edit:

I made a new file and I wrote:

```
x = str(5)
print(x)
```

Result:

```
[error] script [ HelloWorld4 ] stopped with error in line 1
[error] TypeError ( 'str' object is not callable )
```

In the python IDE it works, but with the Sikuli IDE it gives an error. 
I had a python code that worked a bit different in with Sikuli, might be a thing here as well...

Comment: I guess somewhere you are using `str = 'somestring'` which overwrites the str function with a string object.

Comment: Make sure there is no outdated .pyc file as well.

Comment: I opened the Sikuli IDE, made a new file. Put this code in it. Save and run. Same problem.

Comment: Please show the output of: `print(str)`

Comment: Sikuli uses the str() function in code samples. I really doubt that the error is on their side, see here: http://doc.sikuli.org/globals.html#Env.getOSVersion, maybe you adjusted some startup script?

Comment: I did adjust the startup script to find Java 8, will have a look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem. 
It occurs when you make use of Java 8 in combination with Sikuli 1.0.1. 
If I use Java 8 with Sikuli 1.1.0 pre-release, everything does work.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this answer to show you it's working for me, show us the rest of the code you are using:

```
In [1]: nCount = 1

In [2]: class Vrijdag():
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         self.day5('Dummy', nCount)
   ...:     def day5(self, value1, value2):
   ...:         self.value1 = value1
   ...:         self.value2 = value2
   ...:         value2B = str(value2)
   ...:         print(value1)
   ...:         print(value2B)
   ...:         

In [3]: Vrijdag()
Dummy
1
Out[3]: <__main__.Vrijdag instance at 0x8b55cec>
```

Comment: Problem is that I am making a big script where this occurs now. The problem I localized, and I made this small line of code. Given the reactions here could be a sikuli problem. Since some python code there works a bit different wit it.

Comment: We need to see the rest of the code then, we cant guess, anyway, something is happening to value2 variable somewhere, watch it and debug it

Comment: I opened the Sikuli IDE, made a new file. Put this exammple code in it. Save and run. Same problem.

Comment: Write a print type(value2) before the line which is crashing

Comment: value2 is not the problem, str is: [error] TypeError ( 'str' object is not callable )

Comment: They probably use "str" as a variable name somewhere which is very bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined str somewhere before that code

```
str = 'Example'
```

You have to be careful not to override some predefined functions. DONT use `str`, `int`, `list`, `bool`, `dict`, `print`, `len`, etc.

```
# python 2
True = False
if (True == False):
    print('be careful')
```